# 324 Error with Zend_Form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I am receiving Error: 324 in chrome when I am trying to display a form in ZF **v1.12.1**. I have done it exactly as in the official example "The Quickstart Guide" in the official site and still the same. After I found Grumpy's (dont know how the second name is spelled (SORRY ABOUT THAT)) that this code:

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setAction($options['action'])->setMethod('post');

        $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name', array('required' => true));
        $pass = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password', array('required' => true));
        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array('label' => 'Login', 'ignore' => true));
        $this->addElement(array($email, $pass, $submit));
    }
}
```

is better and more useful in my use. Any ways when I try to run either of the examples (in the official docs or hes example) I get this error in chrome:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection
>   without sending any data.

Tryed all possible fixes and everything (firewall off, disable network prediction in chrome and etc.) none helps. When I comment the code when calling the Form everything is back on-line. I am using:

> Version 22.0.1229.94 Ubuntu 12.10 (161065)
>   Chromium

Any possible fix for this issue?

PS: I am calling the form with this code:

```
public function indexAction() 
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Login(array('action' => '/index/index'));

        $this->view->form = $form;


    }
```

only that is in the controller, everything else will be added when the issue is fixed.

PS2:
Wanted to ask here before submiting an issue to ZF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->addElements(array($email, $pass, $submit));`

use `addElements` to add multiple elements